# adding custom column in datatable.js

Tags: jquery, datatable

Good day! Im going to build a Datatable but I found this code on the internet then I decided to use this in stead to make from scratch.. but I dont know how to add a column.. here is the code...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>   
  <html lang="en">   
  <head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Example of Employee Table with twitter bootstrap</title>   
<meta name="description" content="Creating a Employee table with Twitter Bootstrap. Learn with example of a Employee Table with Twitter Bootstrap.">  
 <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>  
  <body style="margin:20px auto">  
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row header" style="text-align:center;color:green">
  <h3>Bootstrap Table With sorting,searching and paging using dataTable.js (Responsive)</h3>
  </div>
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" >  
    <thead>  
      <tr>  
        <th>ENO</th>  
        <th>EMPName</th>  
        <th>Country</th>  
        <th>Salary</th>  
        <th>age</th>  
      </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>  

      <tr>  
        <td>001</td>  
        <td>Anusha</td>  
        <td>India</td>  
        <td>10000</td> 
        <td>25</td> 
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>002</td>  
        <td>Charles</td>  
        <td>United Kingdom</td>  
        <td>28000</td>  

      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>003</td>  
        <td>Sravani</td>  
        <td>Australia</td>  
        <td>7000</td>  
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>  
       <tr>  
        <td>004</td>  
        <td>Amar</td>  
        <td>India</td>  
        <td>18000</td>  
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>005</td>  
        <td>Lakshmi</td>  
        <td>India</td>  
        <td>12000</td>  
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>006</td>  
        <td>James</td>  
        <td>Canada</td>  
        <td>50000</td>  
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>  

       <tr>  
        <td>007</td>  
        <td>Ronald</td>  
        <td>US</td>  
        <td>75000</td> 
        <td>25</td> 
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>008</td>  
        <td>Mike</td>  
        <td>Belgium</td>  
        <td>100000</td> 
        <td>25</td> 
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>009</td>  
        <td>Andrew</td>  
        <td>Argentina</td>  
        <td>45000</td>  
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>  

        <tr>  
        <td>010</td>  
        <td>Stephen</td>  
        <td>Austria</td>  
        <td>30000</td>  
        <td>25</td>
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>011</td>  
        <td>Sara</td>  
        <td>China</td>  
        <td>750000</td>
        <td>25</td>  
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>012</td>  
        <td>JonRoot</td>  
        <td>Argentina</td>  
        <td>65000</td>  
        <td>20</td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>  
  </table>  
  </div>
</body>  
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myTable').dataTable();
 });
 </script>
 </html>
```

the age column is the column that what i'm going to add but some reason this makes an error that says "Datatables warning: table id=myTable...... some code"... you can try to copy that code and run it yourself so that you can find what I mean... thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing data for `Age' for second row in your table.

Current Code

```
 <tr>  
        <td>002</td>  
        <td>Charles</td>  
        <td>United Kingdom</td>  
        <td>28000</td>  
</tr>
```

What you need to do is supply a value for `Age` for this row and you will not get the warning.

Modified Code:

```
<tr>  
        <td>002</td>  
        <td>Charles</td>  
        <td>United Kingdom</td>  
        <td>28000</td>
        <td>31</td>
</tr>
```